# Chart.js is not Dynamically Updating when the firebase databse is updating. (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

This is the Visual.vue code that takes in the data from the firebase database and puts it into the chart.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <chart :chartData="chartData"  class="charts" :width="900" :height="500"></chart>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Chart from "../Chart/Chart.js";
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "../Firebase/firebaseinit.js"

export default {
    components: {
    Chart
    },
    data () {
        return {
        values: [],
        timelabels: [],
        chartData: null,
        };
      },
      created() {
      },
     mounted() {
       this.chartData = {
              labels: this.timelabels,
              datasets: [
              {
                label: "Water Level ",
                borderColor: "white",
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: this.values
              }
            ]
        }
        firebase.database().ref("level").limitToLast(10)
        .on("child_added", snap => {this.values.push(snap.val().Water_Level)
         });
        firebase.database().ref("level").limitToLast(10)
        .on("child_added", snap => {this.timelabels.push(snap.val().Time)
         });        
      },
      method: {
        
      },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.charts {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
```

This is the Chart.js file containing all the configuration of the chart.

```
import {
    Line,
    mixins
} from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
    extends: Line,
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
    props: ['chartData'],
    data() {
        return {
            options: {
                layout: {
                padding: {
                        left: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 20,
                        top: 10
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            fontColor: 'white',
                            maxTicksLimit: 10,

                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                            zeroLineColor: 'red',
                            color: '#313131',
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: 'white'
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                            zeroLineColor: 'red',
                            color: '#313131',
                        }
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: 'white'
                    }
                },
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: false
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me why the chart is not updating? Also, when I refresh the page, the data in the chart disappears. Why? I checked the console, it states 'cannot read property "skip" of undefined'. When i hover over the chart, the number of next to the warning increases as I move the cursor over the chart.

Answer (score 0):

The Chart isn't updating because you are not updating `chartData` anywhere you are just setting it once in mounted then nothing. you need to update it every time you update `values` and `timelabels` maybe like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.chartData = {
        labels: this.timelabels,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: "Water Level ",
            borderColor: "white",
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: this.values
        }]
    }
        firebase.database().ref("level").limitToLast(10)
        .on("child_added", snap => {
             this.values.push(snap.val().Water_Level)
             this.chartData.labels = this.values
         });
        firebase.database().ref("level").limitToLast(10)
        .on("child_added", snap => {
             this.timelabels.push(snap.val().Time)
             this.chartData.datasets[0].data = this.timelabels
         });        
      }
```

As for why the chart disappears when refreshing the page? because of the error `cannot read property "skip" of undefined` my biggest guess is because you are setting `chartData: null` at the beginning. define it like this

```
chartData: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{}]
  }
```

Comment: The chart is still not updating. Also, the data still disappears when refreshed.

Comment: Then make sure that `.on("child_added", snap` is triggered when adding something to the data. As for the data still disappears, it's not vanishing, the flow of the execution just stopped because of the error  `cannot read property "skip" of undefined`. check in the console which line cause it.

Comment: Is it also because the data is being updated asynchronously?

Comment: What are you referring as (it) in the question? :)

Comment: The data being updated asynchronously is maybe the reason why the chart isn't being updated? Maybe, the chart is being rendered first before the data is being updated. Don't really know how to fix that.

Comment: Honesty I'm out of ideas, Try to add some data to   chartData manually in the console and observe the behavior, you will make sure if the problem is from asynchronous changes or the changes not propagating to the chat in the first place.